# Is there anyway to avoid repetitive class instantiations for all methods in the cpp file?

Tags: c++, class, declaration, explicit

Is there any way in which to simplify the explicit statement of the class when implementing methods in the cpp file that was previously contracted in the h file?

Something like...

```
MyClass:: {
void my_method() { implementation };
void my_other() { implementation };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, but a good IDE will offer some Refactoring facilities to ease the typing. For Visual Studio, [VisualAssist](http://wholetomato.com) is a good plugin (not affiliated in any way).

You could optionally create your own macro, something like:

```
// This is very ungly, probably best avoided
#define lessTyping(method) MyClass::##method()

lessTyping(my_method)
{
}
```

But it would really hurt readbility.

Answer (score 0):

No.

C++11 standard `§9.3 [class.mfct] p5`:

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class name using the `::` operator.

Comment: Your lookup function on standard is faster than mine ;) http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf page 154

Comment: @Jack: Wow, that's the C++98 standard. You should *maybe* get an update. :)

Comment: I bookmarked it much time ago and never updated it, everything went fine so far, until I'll find something that seriously got updated :/

Comment: @Jack: [Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)'s the link to N3337, which is the first publicly available Draft after the C++11 standard was ratified, and is basically the standard with a few editorial fixes.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to avoid them is to use inline declaration directly in header file like in

```
class MyClass
{
  void my_method() { implementation };
  ...
}
```